# Should I prefix my variable names for components in GUI code?

Tags: user-interface, prefix, naming-conventions

Some coding books mention that we should not prefix the type in the name, since current IDEs are able to make these visible and clear. I completely agree for primitive types but I'm inclined to still prefix my GUI components variable names.
What are the best practices when working with on GUI code regarding GUI component variable naming?

E.g. should I name my

```
Button btnSubmit
TextField tfName
Checkbox cbActive
```

or

```
Button submit
TextField name
Checkbox active
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that generally, when naming GUI-components, prefixing the variable name with the type of GUI-component simplifies the process of writing code in that when I write code that references them, I don't have to remember the exact name of each component. E.g. often I know that I'm gonna get the text from a specific `TextBox`, but I don't remember the exact name of it. I start typing `TextBox` and up in IntelliSense a range of `TextBox`es appear, from which I easily can identify the exact one I'm in need of.

Regarding if it's any best practices; It depends on

1. If your company has any standards, I'd assume they'd be the best practices in this case.
2. If it's a private project, go with what you feel is the best.

My 0.02$